# How can i change the color of individual icon in list builder

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i change the the color of individual icon in list builder

i want to change the color if a particular task is completed
check the pictures

below is my list generate code
e.g if i complete the Pretest so the Pretest should change into green

```
  Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
              child: GridView.count(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                crossAxisCount: 1,
                mainAxisSpacing: 16,
                childAspectRatio: 4,
                children: List.generate(tagListDisease.length, (index) {
                  return _diseaseCard(tagListDisease[index]),
                  );
                }),
              ),
```

and the _diseaseCardWidgets are below

```
Widget _diseaseCard(tags) {
return Card(
    margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
    ),
    elevation: 0.0,
    child: Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.07,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(width: 3, color: Colors.red ),
                color: Colors.transparent),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "0%",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 8,
            ),
            child: Text(
              "$tags",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 14.0,
                letterSpacing: 1,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[[image: This is normal from first time]]

[image: and i want this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can see working demo below 
Step 1: Use a class `Tag` and `List<Tag>`

```
class Tag {
  String title;
  bool complete;

  Tag({this.title, this.complete});
}
...
List<Tag> tagListDisease = [
    Tag(title: "a", complete: false),
```

Step 2: `Pass List<Tag> tagListDisease` and `index`, and then check `tagListDisease[index].complete`

```
Widget _diseaseCard(List<Tag> tagListDisease, int index) {
    ...
    InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        tagListDisease[index].complete =
            !tagListDisease[index].complete;
        setState(() {});
      },
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.07,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            border: Border.all(
                width: 3,
                color: tagListDisease[index].complete
                    ? Colors.green
                    : Colors.red),
            color: Colors.transparent),
        child: Center(
          child: tagListDisease[index].complete
              ? Icon(
                  Icons.favorite,
                  color: Colors.pink,
                  size: 24.0,
                  semanticLabel:
                      'Text to announce in accessibility modes',
                )
              : Text(
                  "0%",
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Tag {
  String title;
  bool complete;

  Tag({this.title, this.complete});
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Tag> tagListDisease = [
    Tag(title: "a", complete: false),
    Tag(title: "b", complete: false),
    Tag(title: "c", complete: false)
  ];

  Widget _diseaseCard(List<Tag> tagListDisease, int index) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
      ),
      elevation: 0.0,
      child: Container(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                tagListDisease[index].complete =
                    !tagListDisease[index].complete;
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.07,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    border: Border.all(
                        width: 3,
                        color: tagListDisease[index].complete
                            ? Colors.green
                            : Colors.red),
                    color: Colors.transparent),
                child: Center(
                  child: tagListDisease[index].complete
                      ? Icon(
                          Icons.favorite,
                          color: Colors.pink,
                          size: 24.0,
                          semanticLabel:
                              'Text to announce in accessibility modes',
                        )
                      : Text(
                          "0%",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            fontSize: 14.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 8,
              ),
              child: Text(
                "${tagListDisease[index].title}",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  letterSpacing: 1,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: GridView.count(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            crossAxisCount: 1,
            mainAxisSpacing: 16,
            childAspectRatio: 4,
            children: List.generate(tagListDisease.length, (index) {
              return _diseaseCard(tagListDisease, index);
            }),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer , I didn't thought of using a bool here !!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a hardcoded color like you have used here:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            border: Border.all(width: 3, color: Colors.red ),
            color: Colors.transparent),
```

Create `Color _color = Colors.red` and use `_color` in place of `Colors.red`

Then, when a task complete button is pressed or tapped
triggered this function:

> => () {SetState((){
> _color = Colors.green},),}

and to change color of a specific item in the list , you will have to pass the id or index but according the code sample you have provided , this should do the job.

Comment: if you see i use a listBuilder how can i change specific item color.. the above example will aply on all

Comment: as I have mentioned in my answer you will have to use either unique id specified to each item in the list or you will have to use index , you haven't mentioned both of them in your example code.  or you can create a list where a item is added when the button is pressed then change color of only the items which are present in the list , using the same principle.

Comment: if you look at the 1st example i use index  children: List.generate(tagListDisease.length, (index) {
                  return _diseaseCard(tagListDisease[index]),
                  );

Comment: oh sorry how could I miss it... my bad. but that index won't work , if you are syncing the data to local storage or firestore or sharedPreferences then, we could create a list which will contain the name or id of the item and pass a  if else condition to set color dynamically . if the item is in the list then color should be green , else color should be red. That is the only possible solution I could come up with :)

Comment: is it possible to apply if condition on color property.

Comment: yes you will have to apply it to color only  like this => color: "function to detect if item exists in the list" ? Colors.green ? Colors.red;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225105/discussion-between-basudev-nayak-and-shah-haroon).